# How to insert wchar in sqlite using c++?

Tags: c++, sqlite

I have TCHAR array and i want to insert that array into mytable,i am trying like this:-

```
  int val = sqlite3_open("test.db", &db);
    if (val)
    {
        cout << "Can't open database: " << sqlite3_errmsg(db) << "\n";
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Open database successfully\n\n";
        sqlite3_exec(db, "PRAGMA encoding =  UTF-8", NULL, NULL, NULL);
    }
    TCHAR *name = L"ひらがな";
    TCHAR query[50];
    wsprintf(query,"L"insert into myTable (Name, Age) VALUES ('%ws',25)",name);
    int rc = sqlite3_exec(db, (const char*)query, callback, 0, &zErrMsg);
    if (rc != SQLITE_OK)
        {
            cout << "SQL error: " << sqlite3_errmsg(db) << "\n";
            sqlite3_free(zErrMsg);
        }
```

Comment: Perhaps you didn't enable Unicode support on your compiler and `TCHAR` maps to `char` instead of `wchar_t`.

Comment: Change project properties to use `Unicode charset` or `#define _UNICODE` at top of your header file

Comment: First, don't insert values directly into a string holding your SQL statement and try to execute that. Use a prepared statement with placeholders or [Little Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/) will be sad. Second, *if* your wide strings are UTF-16 encoded, you can then bind them to said placeholders with `sqlite3_bind_text16()`.

Answer (score 2):

To expand on my earlier comment:

I don't know what `TCHAR` is but your title is about wchar and you use wide string literals, so I assume it's an alias for `wchar_t`.

Sqlite expects Unicode strings, with APIs that take or return UTF-8 encoded strings and UTF-16 encoded strings. If you're using some other encoding, you have to convert to one of those before storing a string as a sqlite `TEXT` type (You can always store it as a `BLOB` which is just a raw array of bytes if you don't want to or can't convert, but sqlite will treat that differently than it will a string). Internally, strings are stored as UTF-8 by default. With a brand new database, before any tables are created, you can change that to various forms of UTF-16 with the `encoding` pragma. It's ignored once the database has been created, though, and since it defaults to UTF-8 you don't really need to have it in your sample code.

Now, the encoding used by wide strings is implementation and locale dependent. It might be UTF-16, it might not even be Unicode at all (But on my computer it's UTF-32). So in portable code you'd have to convert from a wide string to a UTF-8 or UTF-16 string, the first of which is pretty easy to do. Even better, C++ has UTF-16 string literals you can use instead of wide strings.

The following code shows examples of both using UTF-16 directly and converting wide strings to UTF-8 strings for inserting into a database. It also demonstrates the [usual workflow](https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/stmt.html) of preparing a statement, binding values to it, and executing it.

```
#include <codecvt>
#include <iostream>
#include <locale>
#include <string>
#include <sqlite3.h>

int main() {
  sqlite3 *db;
  int val = sqlite3_open("test.db", &db);
  if (val) {
    std::cerr << "Can't open database: " << sqlite3_errmsg(db) << '\n';
    return 1;
  }

  // Use a ASCII (And thus UTF-8) string
  char *errmsg;
  if (sqlite3_exec(db,
                   "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS myTable(name TEXT, age INTEGER)",
                   nullptr, nullptr, &errmsg) != SQLITE_OK) {
    std::cerr << "Sqlite error: " << errmsg << '\n';
    return 1;
  }

  sqlite3_stmt *stmt;
  // Use a  UTF-16 string literal
  val = sqlite3_prepare16_v2(db, u"INSERT INTO myTable(name,age) VALUES (?,?)",
                             -1, &stmt, nullptr);
  if (val != SQLITE_OK) {
    std::cerr << "Sqlite error: " << sqlite3_errmsg(db) << '\n';
    return 1;
  }

  // Convert a wide string to a UTF-8 string
  std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8<wchar_t>> conv;
  std::wstring name = L"ひらがな";
  auto converted = conv.to_bytes(name);
  // And bind it
  sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 1, converted.c_str(), converted.size(),
                    SQLITE_STATIC);
  sqlite3_bind_int(stmt, 2, 25);
  val = sqlite3_step(stmt);
  if (val != SQLITE_DONE) {
    std::cerr << "Sqlite error: " << sqlite3_errmsg(db) << '\n';
    return 1;
  }
  sqlite3_finalize(stmt);
  sqlite3_close(db);
}
```